# WorksheetChange Event to Concatenate Row and First Letter of First Name + First Letter of Last Name

Tags: excel, vba

I think the code should be something like this, but I'm getting an error on this line where I am trying to handle the first and last names.  Basically, I want to create a code in Column A, which is the first letter of the person's first name and first letter of the person's last name, concatenated with the row number.  The row will be the active row (always Column A) and the first and last names will be stored in Column B.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()"
        TV1 = Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1
        Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=UPPER(LEFT(R[" & "=ROW()" & "]C[1],1)&MID(R[" & "=ROW()" & "]C[1],FIND("" "",R[" & "=ROW()" & "]C[1],1)+1,1))"
        TV2 = Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1
        Target.Offset(0, 0).Value = TV2 & "-" & TV1
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `R[" & "=ROW()" & "]` can be written as `R` if you just want the same row and not offset by a number of rows equal to the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like to avoid dealing with more than a single cell as the Target. It isn't hard to deal with  multiple cells.

After disabling events and performing your processing, you are not turning them back on again. You code will only run once without manually turning events back on.

If you are putting first and last names into column B, shouldn't the processing be subject to column B and not column A?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim trgt As Range
        For Each trgt In Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.UsedRange, Columns("B"))
            trgt = StrConv(Trim(trgt.Value2), vbProperCase)
            If CBool(InStr(2, trgt.Value2, Chr(32))) Then
                trgt.Offset(0, -1) = _
                    UCase(Left(trgt.Value2, 1)) & _
                    UCase(Mid(trgt.Value2, InStr(1, trgt.Value2, Chr(32)) + 1, 1)) & _
                    Format(trgt.Row, "000")
            End If
        Next trgt
    End If

ErrHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I've added some trim and proper-case conversion to auto-correct the values being typed into column B.

In the following image, I copied the names from G5:G8 and pasted them into B2:B5.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would do this differently.  Why write formulas when you can do it simply in VBA?

I've made some annotations to your original code also:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub

  Application.EnableEvents = False

' No error handler in your code
'On Error GoTo ErrHandler

' don't need to check if column 1 since we already did that and exited the sub if it was not
'    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        'Target.Offset(0,0) = Target
        'Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()"
        'TV1 = Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1
        'Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=UPPER(LEFT(R[" & "=ROW()" & "]C[1],1)&MID(R[" & "=ROW()" & "]C[1],FIND("" "",R[" & "=ROW()" & "]C[1],1)+1,1))"
        'TV2 = Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1
        'Target.Offset(0, 0).Value = TV2 & "-" & TV1

        'Just do the creation in VB
        With Target
            .Value = .Row & Left(.Offset(0, 1), 1) & Left(Split(.Offset(0, 1))(1), 1)
        End With

        'If you have more than two space-separated words in the name, then something like
        Dim V As Variant
        With Target
            V = Split(.Offset(0, 1))
            .Value = .Row & Left(V(0), 1) & Left(V(UBound(V)), 1)
        End With

'Don't forget to reenable events
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

---

Also, since the names are in Column B, why are you testing for a change in Column A?  There could be reasons, but if there are not, it might be smoother to check for changes in column B.

Comment: Yeah, that all makes sense now.  Thanks for the look!!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!!

```
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()"
    TV1 = Target.Value
    Target.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=UPPER(LEFT(RC[1],1)&MID(RC[1],FIND("" "",RC[1],1)+1,1))"
    TV2 = Target.Value
    Target.Value = TV2 & "-" & TV1
End If
```